# How to animate an object rotating on its own axis?

Tags: animation, transforms, coordinates

I want to animate a planet spinning on a slight tilt, like the earth does. I want to use a generator (in the graph editor) to have consistent, procedural motion, but animating any single axis of rotation uses global coordinates. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you animate the earth on the Z axis, then parent it to an empty, and tilt a bit this empty, is it not what you want?

[image]